# Notepad ++ Script or sort with RegEx?

Tags: notepad++

I have data like this :

```
Location Name......................: DRC-BOH
Location description...............: DRC-BOH-locationinfo
Policy tag.........................: PT_33_52
Site tag...........................: DCA_Campus_Site_Tag
RF tag.............................: DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
Configured list of APs
xxxx.98ff.6264   
xxxx.21a1.829c   
Location Name......................: DL-cb
Location description...............: DL-cb-locationinfo
Policy tag.........................: PT_23_26_52
Site tag...........................: DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag
RF tag.............................: DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
Configured list of APs
xxxx.c82a.3a10   
xxxx.8b62.527c   
xxxx.7a97.afe4   
xxxx.7ad9.8f88   
xxxx.2d9d.ffe8   
xxxx.806e.dd50   
xxxx.9cd9.7890   
xxxx.781e.84d6   
xxxx.785a.bf9e   
xxxx.9844.0a84   
xxxx.987b.9ec4   
xxxx.2f86.d7cc   
xxxx.2fb1.4528   
xxxx.396a.0b6a   
xxxx.d69f.c234   
xxxx.5dd7.bbe8   
xxxx.5ded.2858   
xxxx.1dd6.33b8   
xxxx.8835.11ac   
xxxx.47df.9fee   

 more of the same....
```

I need to have this in the end...:

```
xxxx.98ff.6264,DRC-BOH,PT_33_52,DCA_Campus_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.21a1.829c,DRC-BOH,PT_33_53,DCA_Campus_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.c82a.3a10,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.8b62.527c,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.7a97.afe4,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.7ad9.8f88,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.2d9d.ffe8,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.806e.dd50,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.9cd9.7890,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.781e.84d6,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.785a.bf9e,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.9844.0a84,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.987b.9ec4,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.2f86.d7cc,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.2fb1.4528,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.396a.0b6a,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.d69f.c234,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.5dd7.bbe8,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.5ded.2858,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.1dd6.33b8,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.8835.11ac,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
xxxx.47df.9fee,DL-cb,PT_23_26_52,DL_Campus_1_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag
rest with same pattern...........
```

I think this will be multiple steps. I am very new to notepad++ but want to learn more about regex and notepad ++ sorting. Any help would be appreciated.

I have been doing it manually by cutting the "configured list of APs" out and using crtl+alt, then pasting each field while adding commmas . There are more than 2500 Aps so i keep thinking there is a better way.

Comment: What have you tried?
Where are your attempts?
What doesn't work?

Comment: You can try vertical copy / paste : https://superuser.com/questions/1110754/copy-and-paste-in-a-column-in-notepad

Answer (score 1):

See https://regex101.com/r/p6SWd6/1 (code below)

Replace

```
Location Name......................: (.+)
Location description...............: (.+)
Policy tag.........................: (.+)
Site tag...........................: (.+)
RF tag.............................: (.+)
Configured list of APs
(?:.{4}\.*
)*?.{4}\..{4}\..{4}(?=\s*\n)
```

with

```
$0,$1,$3,$4,$5
```

however many times you need

Comment: This doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: I will look at this. Thanks! I do not have time at the moment but i will try soon.

Comment: so, i am not completely sure what i am looking at in the regex but the MAC addresses i listed only start with xxxx in order not show the original content, it was just some fake examples. The mac addresses in the list could have any hex letter in numbers at the beginning.  they could be something like  683b.78f1.36d8 or cc16.7ef7.f78c for example.

Comment: @KyleYoumans well, garbage in - garbage out, gonna fix. Next time provite more trustworthy-*looking* information, like I did replacing all xxxx with a copy of correct one

Comment: sorry. it was a dumb attempt at obfuscating data. I think i understand some of what you had. In the data i a trying to sort, there are 362 sets of location groups for around 2500 access points.  this is a more complete sample of data

Comment: I come from a Networking background and I am attempting to be more versatile, hence i am trying pick up some skills that can assist me with sorting large amounts of configuration files.  i should not of assumed that you understood that those were MAC addresses. I know people that do not have a networking background would not of picked up on this just as i have a hard time picking up on Regex things.

Comment: I see the revision and i understand most of it. What i am missing is how this gets implemented in Notepad ++. If I do a regex search and replace, there is no areas for this much date in the "find" field. i understand that you have defined each variable with "(.+) and i understand that $0,$1,$3,$4,$5 is the replace. i guess i just do not understand how to start this procedure. Is this just an example function for a higher level script? I know there is a plug in for Python.

Comment: I am guessing that this information would be helpful to attempt a Python script but again, I am pretty new at the scripting world. I thank you for your time.

Comment: @KyleYoumans All the modern editors have regex replacers builtin (Ctrl+H to open, `.*` mode). I would be surprized if N+ doesn't have that

Comment: N++ does but only one line regex is available. A complex function does not seem possible. i would be better off just taking each of the 360 different locations and making a single txt file for each location and doing it manually with "find "([0-9a-f]{4}[\.][0-9a-f]{4}[\.][0-9a-f]{4})" and replace "\1,H2100-DRC,PT_33_52,DTD_ESP_Site_Tag,DLR-Indoor_rf_tag"

Comment: I just do not see a way to do all the mac addresses at once with their correct location information. This was the root of my question.

Comment: @KyleYoumans you just have to click "replace all" 100-200 times

Comment: well. There are 360 separate variables of :
Location Name......................:
Location description...............:
Policy tag.........................:
Site tag...........................:
RF tag.............................:

Each of the 360 sets of variables have 1 -500 aps under them. does this make sense?

Comment: so the replace is \1,locationname, policytag,sitetag,rftag for each set of aps where there are 1 to 500 aps that need those particular variables that are not the same as the last.